# p:fileIUpload not calling listener in liferay after updates

Tags: primefaces, liferay, liferay-7

I have upgraded my application from primefaces 7.0 to 8.0 and liferay-ce-portal-7.1.2-ga3 to liferay-ce-portal-7.2.0-ga1 (tomcat server) and jsf version 2.2.18.

After this upgrade I noticed that `p:fileUpload` component is not working fine any more. Before upgrading I was using `fileUploadListener` attribute in `p:fileUpload` component. But this attribute is not available in PrimeFaces version 8.0, so I changed the attribute to `listener`

code below:

**xhtml part**

```
<p:fileUpload label="Upload" auto="true"
        styleClass="button" listener="#{loginBean.handleProfileImageUpload}"
        skinSimple="true" update="@all" mode="advanced"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" fileLimit="1" />
```

**bean part**

```
public void handleProfileImageUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        try {
            file = event.getFile();
            loggedInUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.updatePortrait(loggedInUser.getUserId(),
                    FileUtil.getBytes(file.getInputStream()));
            long portraitId = loggedInUser.getPortraitId();
            String tokenId = WebServerServletTokenUtil.getToken(loggedInUser.getPortraitId());
            String img_id_token = HttpUtil.encodeURL(DigesterUtil.digest(loggedInUser.getUuid()));

            profilePath = "image/user_" + ((loggedInUser != null) && loggedInUser.isFemale() ? "female" : "male")
                    + "_portrait?img_id=" + portraitId + "&img_id_token=" + img_id_token + "&t=" + tokenId;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it was working fine with liferay before. this stops working after upgrading as i mentioned which things i have upgraded.

Comment: @Kukeltje i also tried with valuechangelistener but still didn't work

Comment: You could temporarily add some logging to make sure your listener is still called. Sometimes a partial project build or deployment messes things up.

Comment: @JensPiegsa i did try building and deploying the project again. if i call remote command oncomplete of p:fileupload with attribute value="{loginBean.file} in this case file is null.

Comment: @UmairMunawarKhokhar Just another thought: Could you check in the browser, whether you are using the right `jquery.js`?

Comment: @JensPiegsa im not using any jquery explicitly. there's an inherited jquery.

Comment: But aren't both PrimeFaces and Liferay shipping a version of JQuery? Which one gains priority?

Comment: @JensPiegsa may be so should i use "var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);" this, what you say

Comment: Cheers! Thanks... lets contiunue positively!

Comment: @Kukeltje sure. Cheers!... so tell me what information do you need from my side? i added liferay word because i thought may be its because of liferay compatibility with primefaces version or something like that...

Comment: Yes, that might be the underlying cause. But what you should check is there is an http request, if your listener is called (like @JensPiegsa stated) , does it end up in the faces servlet (run in debug, set breakpoints), What if you run your project in JSF development mode? What if you turn the log level up on things in your server? These are things I always do (what ever technology I'm using, currently old tapestry things) when investigating things.

Comment: @Kukeltje i have tried with the break points but the problem is it never go into the body(listener) of the funtion. not hitting the bean method.

Comment: this is another way i tried 
`<p:fileUpload value="#{loginBean.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" /> <p:commandButton value="Upload" ajax="false" action="#{loginBean.handleProfileImageUpload}" />`  and the bean method is

`public void handleProfileImageUpload() {
  try {
  System.out.println(file.getFileName());
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

this time on clicking upload button, its hitting the function but with null file and giving **null pointer** exception

Comment: But in all these cases, IS there an http request going out? Does it end up in the faces servelet or on the portletbridge? Are there client side errors? etc... And extensive code attempts should be added to the question. More readble Then just ad a small comment about the change in the comments